# Adobe Flash installed in Firefox, but not in Chromium, getting install error Error - AptUrl: The channel 'utopic-partner' is not know

Tags: adobe-flash, kubuntu

I've installed Adobe Flash in Firefox succesfully and all works fine, but I cannot it get running under Chrome. If I try to install .apt Adobe Flash install file from Chrome, I get error in screenshot:[image: Chromium Flash Install Error]. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its Chrome, downloaded from Google, then it already includes Flash. You don't need to install it separately.

If this is Chromium, installed via `apt` (or any of its frontends) from the Ubuntu/Kubuntu repositories, you should install Flash like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
$ sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

BTW: There is a similar `flashplugin-nonfree` package and corresponding `update-flashplugin-nonfree --install` command that can be used for Iceweasel/Firefox.

Comment: Luckily it fixed my Opera too on Kubuntu 15.04.